# jQuery fade-in and fade-out weird flicker at the end of fade-in

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a list of images that I would like fade out and then fade in after the user clicks on a link in a list. For some reason when I click on the links in the list the item will fade in but just before it's done fading in it will fadeout and back in really quickly!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.service-link').click(function(){ return switch_service(this); });
});

function switch_service( link ) {
    var slug = $(link).attr('href');

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(link).addClass('active');

    $('.service-li:visible').fadeOut( 300, function(){
        $(slug).fadeIn( 300 );
    } );
    return false;
}
```

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<ul id="services-info">
    <li class="service-li" id="slug-1"><img src="..." /></li>
    <li class="service-li" id="slug-2"><img src="..." /></li>
    <li class="service-li" id="slug-3"><img src="..." /></li>
    <li class="give-height"></li>
</ul>

<ul id="services-list">
    <li><a class="service-link" href="#slug-1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="service-link" href="#slug-2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="service-link" href="#slug-3">Test 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm not really sure what's different. I've done this sort of thing before and had no problem. Sometimes functions might be a little wonky because of quick clicks between items but this time around it happens every time (tested in both FF and Chrome).

Edit: Okay so I made my example more faithful to what's running on my page by adding extra IDs and an empty list-item with a class to keep my ul with hidden elements from collapsing. I didn't originally post my CSS because it didn't occur to me that it could be the problem, here goes:

```
#services-list,
#services-info {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 465px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#services-list:after,
#services-info:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

#services-info > li {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}

#services-list {
    padding-left: 50px;
    color: #cacaca;
}

#services-list a {
    color: #cacaca;
}

#services-list a.active {
    color: #bed545;
}

#services-info .give-height {
    display: block;
    min-height: 30px;
}

#services-info > li {
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

To show exactly what's going on, here's the [testing link](http://bbandm.bbandmhosting.com/services/) but I will be removing it once this question is answered (sorry for people who might be having this problem in the future, hopefully I can describe the problem well enough for this to still be useful)

Comment: What's the CSS for your `active` class?

Comment: I plugged your above code into jsFiddle, tested in Chrome, and everything just fades out when I click a link, but nothing fades in. Is this code working for you?

Comment: can you create a fiddle demonstrating this please?

Comment: Nevermind, just noticed the ids for lis all start with "#", so after fixing the ids, clicking the links make the images fade out and one fades back in, nice and smooth. Put up some code on jsFiddle.net and see if you can replicate your problem, then post a list

Comment: Sorry guys, I wrote the HTML quickly because I didn't want to paste all the paths and such. I'll fix the HTML because there shouldn't be a # in the ID for the list-items on the top list. That's what's breaking the fade-in I think. The active class only changes the colour of the text. I'll try and post a jsfiddle.

Comment: Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUuHV/) if anyone wants to play with it. The fading in and out seems to work OK to me (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long guys, I ended up going home but I'm back now. If you click on the link the only service with an image is the "broadcast production" link.